# Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' API Youtube

Tags: javascript, youtube

La situación es la siguiente:

Tengo 2 videos de youtube que se encuentran ocultos, cuando acciono el link este me abre el video.

Ahora intentando utilizar la API de Youtube, la cual quiero que me arroje algunos datos, me marca el siguiente error:

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow'
```

Cabe mencionar que estoy en local y quiero saber a que se debe ese problema.

Este es mi codigo:

```
$("#primervideo").click(function(e){
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);             
        });
        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            var player;
            player = new YT.Player('yt_video', {
                events: {
                    'onStateChange': onStateChange
                }
            });
        }
```

Este lo ocupo cuando yo le doy clic al enlace que llama al iframe,obviamente este iframe está oculto y se activa mediante un link

```
<iframe  width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/RSo2gq8wTYw?autoplay=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&version=3&enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Por favor, publica su código.

Comment: @TheProHands Ya puse mi codigo, me he dado cuenta que cuando el video se encuentra presente desde que se carga la página, el codigo se ejecuta sin el error que menciono, pero si este no se encuentra me marca el error, como podría solucionar esto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero, la URL que usas no es válida. Segundo, al final de la URL encontrás el ID del video. Ejemplo:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ANS9sSJA9Yc 
>   ID=ANS9sSJA9Yc

Tercero, podés usar un div en lugar de un iframe?

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

Y desde el JS:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: '390',
        width: '640',
        videoId: 'ANS9sSJA9Yc',
        events: {
            'onReady': function onPlayerReady(event) {
              player.setPlaybackRate(2);
              event.target.playVideo();
          }
        }
    });
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/zbg11a2h/

Comment: Gracias, no había revisado tu solución y funciono!! Tenía estancado este problema.